# batch file from controller - how to execute on server side

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I understand this might not be the best idea - but I am trying to test running a batch file on a post to send a msg.exe message to a user. This works when using IIS express locally, but once I publish to my intranet site it does not work - no errors just no message. Any ideas?

```
                        string filepath = "C:\\msg\\msg.bat";
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filepath);
```

Comment: Double check the file path. I'm guessing the virtual path doesn't match up with the file structure on your computer. Generally you'd want to use a web.config file (or another form of configuration) so then you can just change the item in the config file, instead of having to go back in, change string literals, and recompile and publish.

Comment: Maybe on the server the web process can't access that folder (or anything outside of its own path) for security reasons?  Maybe that file doesn't exist on the server?

Comment: on the server itself I created c:\msg\msg.bat. I assume that is where it is looking.

Comment: have you tried executing msg.bat directly on the server? Does it work? Maybe the user account under which MVC is running doesn't have permission to run the command or something

Comment: Also is there any specific reason you need to use msg.exe especially? What's wrong with email, or SMS, or whatsapp, or some other more conventional way of communicating?